# How to make the Rich Text area larger?

Tags: custom-fields, fieldtype, fields, richtext

I'm using the standard EE 'Textarea (Rich Text)' field (on EE 2.10.1), but no matter what I put in the 'Textarea Rows' field, when viewing the field in the control panel it's only around 150 pixels tall.

I can of course drag the bottom right hand corner of the field to make it display more of its contents but it's a pain to have to do this each time.

Is this a known bug or is there a way to get this field to display deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you inspected the field using your developer console? Oh, and FYI, this isn't an EE question. Textarea rows constraint has **nothing to do** with styling, just how many rows are allowed to be typed.

Want a different height? You need to style it with CSS:

```
textarea {
    height: 666px;
    width: 999px;
}
```

Use this:

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js

to add custom CSS to your Control Panel.